# What are the valid range of values for the UIImpactFeedbackGenerator class's impactOccurredWithIntensity method?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uikit

The iOS UIKit class [UIImpactFeedbackGenerator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimpactfeedbackgenerator), in iOS 13+, has an instance method [impactOccurredWithIntensity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimpactfeedbackgenerator/3183920-impactoccurredwithintensity), which takes a single `CGFloat` parameter, `intensity`. The documented declaration is (in Objective-C):

```
- (void)impactOccurredWithIntensity:(CGFloat)intensity;
```

As of the time of this question, the linked documentation page provides no information on what the valid range of values are for that `intensity` parameter, and what effect the value has.

(Is the range 0 to 1? 0 to infinity? Some other maximum? Are negative values permitted? Do larger values generate more intense haptic feedback? How does the `intensity` value interact with the various [`UIImpactFeedbackStyle` values](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimpactfeedbackstyle), such as `UIImpactFeedbackStyleHeavy`, that the `UIImpactFeedbackGenerator` can be initialized with?)

Also as of the time of this question, a simple [Google search for `impactOccurredWithIntensity`](https://www.google.com/search?q=impactOccurredWithIntensity) yields no meaningful results beyond that linked Apple documentation page.

My question: What are the valid range of values for the `intensity` parameter of the `impactOccurredWithIntensity` method, and what specific effect does the value have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `intensity` parameter is a value between `0.0` and `1.0`, which is intended to represent the force of the impact. (The header declaration and documentation for this method both indicate this; the documentation may have been updated since you asked the question originally.) In terms of how it affects the haptic output, you can think of `intensity` as the volume/strength of the haptic vibration that gets played for each impact.

When you initialize an impact feedback generator, the `style` you choose is intended to describe the physical attributes of the UI elements involved in the impact, for example whether they are light, heavy, soft, or rigid. The `style` affects the type of haptic waveform that is played when an impact occurs, for example whether the vibration is more of a quick sharp tap, a dull thud, etc.

The reason that the `style` is baked in to the `UIImpactFeedbackGenerator` when it is initialized is because the `style` should remain consistent across multiple impacts for the same UI elements. On the other hand, the `intensity` is a parameter for each impact, as it's generally a function of how fast the UI elements were moving when they collided.

It's up to you to determine which parameters work best for your use case. Choosing how to map different impact velocities to the normalized `0.0 - 1.0` range of `intensity` is something you get to define. Ultimately, you'll want to experiment and tune the parameters on a real device to produce a compelling experience that adds to the interaction, without being distracting.